# How can I capture only one part of Perl regular expression with grouping?

Tags: regex, perl, capture

I've currenly trying to pull out dates from a file and feed them directly into an array. My regex is working, but I have 6 groups in it, all of which are being added to the array, when I only want the first one.

```
@dates = (@dates, ($line =~ /((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(\/|\-)(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\/|\-)([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9]))/g ));
```

is there a simple way to grab the $1 group of a perl regex?

my output is looking like this:

```
13/04/2009, 13, /, 04, /, 2009, 14-12-09, 14, -, 12, -, 09
```

Comment: Why fetch them all if you only want the first?  Using parens causes them to be returned.  But if you have to fetch them all, just undef the values you don't want.

Comment: Please add an example of the source string that you are trying to parse.

Comment: What happens when you lop off the `g` at the end of the regex?

Comment: @heferav I was trying to pull out either xx/xx/xx, xx/xx/xxxx, xx-xx-xx or xx-xx-xxxx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That regex looks like the sort of thing that would confuse me when I next pick up the code.
I would break it out :

```
    my $date= qr/
       (?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])           # day
       (?:\/|\-)
       (?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])                    # month
       (?:\/|\-)
       (?:[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9])  #year
       /x ;
```

You can add the element onto the array using

```
    push @dates,   ($line =~ /($date)/ ) ;
```

You an simplify the seperator bit (notice I have changed to using `( )` rather than `/ /` to avoid having to backslahs the `/`

```
    my $date= qr (
       (?: 0[1-9] | [12][0-9] | 3[01]       # day
       [/-]
       (?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])                    # month
       [/-]
       (?:\d{4}|\d{2})                      #year
       )x ;
```

Comment: thanks justintime. yeah, definitely more legible. still getting my head around regexs.

Answer (score 1):

just found it. You can create a passive group by using `?:` at the start of the group.

```
@dates = (@dates, ($line =~ /((?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(?:\/|\-)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:\/|\-)(?:[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9]))/g ));
```

by making all other groups passive, now only the first group is added to the array.

Comment: In addition, you are using more parentheses than you need. For example, `(?:\/|\-)` can be `[\/-]`. Also, don't forget that `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` can be `\d{4}`.